# How to call a JAX-WS web service with mandatory transaction from Java SE?

Tags: java, ejb, jax-ws

There is an EJB stateless bean representing a JAX-WS web service that has the following annotation:

```
@Transactional(value = Transactional.TransactionFlowType.MANDATORY, version = Transactional.Version.DEFAULT)
```

I need to invoke this web service from a Java SE app (actually, from an executable jar, not sure if it changes things). I've generated required classes using `wsimport` but get the following error when calling web service:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: transaction context is required to be inflowed
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:178)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:117)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:135)
```

From what I understand, client must be in a transaction when calling web service. I've tried searching online for a solution but to no avail. What are the ways to accomplish this task?

Comment: That `@Transactional(value = Transactional.TransactionFlowType.MANDATORY, ...` looks vendor specific because it's not the Java EE [javax.transaction.Transactional](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/transaction/Transactional.html) annotation (it has different arguments). You may need to find the documentation for that implementation. Note that transactional SOAP web services are not common so you're likely going to have to dig this one out yourself.